# input type=number does not change on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I have a simple number input element:

```html
<input type="number" id="test" min="0" max="100" value="50">
```

Earlier I could change the value of the element just by scrolling inside the input element. But I could not do that anymore with Chrome version 100. Is this some kind of bug in Chrome or has something changed in the recent version of Chrome?

Also, I noticed if I add a blank event listener to that element then it works properly in Chrome:

```js
document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('wheel', () => { })
```

```html
<input type="number" id="test" min="0" max="100" value="50">
```

Comment: This has nothing at all to do with java. Removed the tag. Did you perhaps mean `javascript` (which is related to `java` the same way hamsters are related to ham. As in, not at all).

Comment: @rzwitserloot  I always find that comparison a little over the top, if you look at the history of Javascript and how it was created,  there is more ancestry going on than a slice of pig & rodent.   Yes, there not the same, and the Tags shouldn't be mixed, but was just my two cents.. :)

Comment: Yes, might be worth reporting to the Chrome dev's.   I would expect while the input has focus, scrollwheel should spin with or without the event listener attached..

Comment: @Keith I wonder which 2 words sound quite similar and do have a certain etymological relationship (unlike, say, 'hamburger' and 'ham' which are etymologically unrelated, and presumably 'ham' and 'hamster', I don't think those are related either) - but are otherwise __utterly__ different. Would make for a better simile.

Comment: @rzwitserloot  Yeah, I think your Ham & Hamburger is much better.  Some genealogy can then be inferred.. :)